# optics/dbscan/hdbscan in RStudio

Tags: r, dbscan, hdbscan, optics-algorithm

So I have "punkty" data which has Lat, Long and geometry, "punkty2" data which is just Lat and Long. And a shapefile "osiedla".

I need to make cluster of the data using optics, dbscan and hdbscan from the dbscan package and show the clusters on the "osiedla" map.

I coded that:

```
db <- dbscan(punkty2, eps = 0.002, minPts = 3)

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = osiedla, fill = "gray95", color = "grey45") +
  geom_sf(data = punkty, color = db$cluster+1, alpha = .7) +
  theme_bw()

hdb <- hdbscan(punkty2, minPts = 15)

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = osiedla, fill = "gray95", color = "grey45") +
  geom_sf(data = punkty, color = hdb$cluster+1, alpha = .7) +
  theme_bw()

o <- optics(punkty2, eps = 0.002, minPts = 3)

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = osiedla, fill = "gray95", color = "grey45") +
  geom_sf(data = punkty, color = o$cluster+1, alpha = .7) +
  theme_bw()
```

And the first two work no problem, but the last one does not. It says:

Error in `geom_sf()`:
! Problem while setting up geom aesthetics.
i Error occurred in the 2nd layer.
Caused by error in `check_aesthetics()`:
! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (2000)
x Fix the following mappings: `colour`

What's wrong?